# How to use AND/OR conditions with dynamic variables on Where Clause using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi I am really confused on how I can add "AND / OR" condition on my where statement if the variable is dynamic? I am actually scraping a content.

My Code is this:

```
self.curr.execute("SELECT Count(post_id) from tesla_news_items WHERE 
post_id = %s COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci",(item['post_id'],) )
```

My logic is something like this:

```
Where post_id = %s , (item['post_id'],) AND title = %s, (item['title],)
```

Anyone who can help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already seem to know how to use a parameterized query. The addition of "or" or "and" should not make much of a difference.

```
self.curr.execute("SELECT Count(post_id) from tesla_news_items WHERE 
post_id = %s COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci AND title = %s", (item['post_id'], item['title']))
```